# Tried to reverse engineer my app, but got some weird-looking file tree

Tags: java, android, reverse-engineering, dex

I lost the code from all the apps I built last year (thunder against my hard disk, no backup for any app). As they were rather simple apps, I put them under reverse engineering process. I have already done this a dozens of time in the past, each time I had no problems at all (if we do not count hours of work to put together all the files into a single project). I have already finished 3 apps I lost during hard disk burnout. They were reversed almost flawlessly, but I got stuck with this one.

Let's get in details. The reverse engineering process went well. I was able to get the XML code from the coded XML files pulled from the APK. I was also able to successfully decompile Java code from the `classes.dex`. I got all files readable and I can open/view then via the text editor.

BUT I got a **weird-looking file structure** and **weird file names**. The project files were located inside the usual path `src/com/mycompanyname/appname`. After RI process, **some** of the files remained in the main path (`R.java`, 3rd party Ad files and a few others), while **all the other files were renaimed** into file structure like this:

a.java
b.java
c.java
...
z.java

All the files I wrote were renamed and got these weird names, while all 3rd party files remained intact.

**Q:** Could anyone tell me what could be the reason for this?

**Q:** Has Eclipse somehow obfuscated the code before compiling it into APK? Is this how the obfuscated APK looks like after being put through IR process?

I really hope someone will be able to help me as I still have to reconstruct more than 10 other apps. It

Comment: Small tip: If you can't recover the projects' code, you might want to check eclipse local history in the workspace directory : ".metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.history"

Comment: Original hard disk is gone, burned after thunderstorm so I guess all the history is gone as well :))))

Comment: Upvote for a good tip, now I know one more directory to backup as well

Comment: You should use a private/public repository instead for all your projects. ;)

Comment: @h3xStream Could you please be specific? Which one do you recommend?

Comment: The real answer for this question is always: Backup. Backup often. Backup offsite. Make sure backups work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Android SDK includes Proguard to obfuscate your code. Proguard is enabled by default when you create an Android project in Eclipse using ADT. You can turn it off however. Read more about this here http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

So...

> Q: Could anyone tell me what could be the reason for this?

It's Proguard doing its job.

> Q: Has Eclipse somehow obfuscated the code before compiling it into
>   APK? Is this how the obfuscated APK looks like after being put through
>   IR process?

It's not Eclipse by itself, it's Proguard that is called in the building process. And yes, that is how it looks like.

Comment: Thanks, upvote. Is there any tool which can help me here? It's funny that I got 26 java classes out of 10-15 classes from the original code. Proguard must have split the original classes into 2 or more classes.

Comment: I don't think there is. The whole point of this is to difficult RI. Your best chance is to look at code and try reconstructing it by figuring the semantics and building a mapping table, it will be EXTREMELY painful though.

Comment: What about your keystore file? Do you have it? Without it you won't be able to update your apps in the market.

Comment: @bergnam: Proguard didn't split the classes. The "extra" classes you're seeing are almost certainly inner classes. Both named inner classes or anonymous inner classes will typically show up as separate classes in the reverse engineering process.

Comment: @JesusFreke You may be right as I cannot recall how many classes + subclasses the app had. But are you absolutely sure it DOES NOT create extra clases? I have RIed some high-traffic random app from the Market which had obfuscated code and it had exactly the same number of java file (24, all letters except letter Y and Z)

Comment: @aromero Yes, the private sign key is safely stored to ext HD prior to the accident.

Comment: @bergnam - it's easy enough to test. create a simple android app that contains an inner class, make the apk and run proguard on it, and take a look at the results.

Answer (score -3):

Just use JAD. to decompile it properly.

Comment: The question is not how to decompile the class/dex files but why it was obfuscated.

Comment: I do not have problems decompiling the code. @aromero said why the structure is looking so weird.